# Python add index number behind string

Tags: python, pandas, string, indexing, numbers

Is there a way to add the index number behind a string in another column? I have already tried used df.index but then I get the error that the ValueError: Length of values (0) does not match length of index (4). Or this error TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations.

```
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
index = df.index
  
dier = 'BRUINVIS-' + index
df['dier'] = dier
```

Error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (4)
```

Comment: Please, be more precise. Show example, expected output and what output you get. We can't help you if we don't understand the question properly

Comment: Sorry I'm gonna write my code done here:

df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
index = df.index

dier = 'BRUINVIS-' + index 
df['dier'] = dier

And this is the error I get: ValueError: Length of values (2) does not match length of index (4)

Answer (score 0):

```
df.index = ['BRUINVIS-' + idx for idx in df.index]
```

Comment: Thanks! But now I get this error TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: `df.index = ['BRUINVIS-' + str(idx) for idx in df.index]`

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':['row', 'row', 'row']})
print(df)
df['column_1'] = df['column_1'] + df.index.astype(str)
print(df)

      column_1
    0      row
    1      row
    2      row
      column_1
    0     row0
    1     row1
    2     row2
```